# SSH works both ways, but scp and rsync only one way

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, debian, rsync, scp

I have been using SCP and rsync to transfer some files between two servers using SSH keys.

Suddently SCP and rsync don't work anymore from server 1 to server 2. They don't give any error or information. Whenever I try to use them, they just hang.

If I try to SSH between servers, it works just great. If I try to scp or rsync from server 2 to server 1 it works great. If I try it from server 1 it doesn't.

This is what I'm trying.

From server 1: `scp /storage/somefile root@server2:/storage` (doesn't work)

From server 2: `scp root@server1:/storage/somefile /storage` (works)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try lowering the MTU on server1?

Comment: Did you try running scp in verbose mode and see what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem.

From server 1 I was using `scp /storage/somefile root@server2domain:/storage` instead of using the ip.

The weird thing is that it worked for over 6 months and it stopped working yesterday out of the blue.

Comment: This suggests you have a dns issue in the client. I see this sometimes if my vpn goes derpy and can't resolve office host names properly.